# If I've already created a registry entry on 2 servers, when I roll it out to the rest of the estate via Group Policy , is it "Update" or "Create"?

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

If I've already created a registry entry on 2 test servers, when I roll it out to the rest of the estate via Group Policy , do I choose "Update" or "Create"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Create, if the registry value already exists it will not be overwritten. You want Update, which is the default.